# Specifying dependencies on makefile

Tags: makefile

I hope that this is obvious to someone out there. I am creating a makefile that I need some special compilation for.  I have cuda files and c++ files each need to be compiled separately.  I want to be able to specify the file and then list the dependencies for the final output in terms of the

```
CUDA_FILES := file1.cu file2.cu file3.cu
CPP_FILES := file4.cpp file5.cpp

# lots of options

#rules:
all: project1

project1: file1.o file2.o file3.o file4.o file5.o
  $(LD) $(LDLIBS) $^ -o $@

%.o: %.cu
  $(CUDA) $(CUDA_ARCH) $(CUDA_OPTIONS) $(CUDA_INCLUDES) -Xcompiler "$(COMPILER OPTIONS" $^ -o $@
```

for the line with `project1:` how do I automatically generate the object list from the files lists to specify as a dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CUDA_FILES := $(wildcard *.cu)
CC_FILES := $(wildcard *.cpp)

OBJS := $(CUDA_FILES:.cu=.o) $(CC_FILES:.cc=.o)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just list the object files instead of the source files:

```
$ cat Makefile
OBJS = a.o b.o

foo: a.o b.o
        $(LD) -o $@ $^
$ make
cc    -c -o a.o a.c
cc    -c -o b.o b.c
ld -o foo a.o b.o
```

**Edit**: If you don't want to follow this method, use [string substitution](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/make/make_6.html#SEC59):

```
OBJS = $(CUDA_FILES:%.cu=%.o) $(CPP_FILES:%.cpp=%.o)
```

Comment: what if I'm using a wildcard search for the files? object files won't come up. `CUDA_FILES := $(wildcard *.cu)`

Comment: `$(CUDA_FILES:%.cu=%.o)` and similarly for `$(CPP_FILES)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the more modern string substitution functions, like:

```
dogCpp := dog.cpp dogSays.cpp
dogObj := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,${dogCpp})
```